# Webpage not showing correct result after print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to print a webpage. In the web print preview, it is showing properly, but when I actually print it on paper, the text doesn't show properly.
Some `float:right` properties are not working and similarly bootstrap grid too.
You can see the issue in picture.

[image]

See at the top "To" section. The text is properly aligned. Also the text at the bottom "Total", "Grand total" etc are `float:right` in actual page, but when I print they are not `float:right`.
[image]

html and css:

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
  }
  .col-xs-1,
  .col-xs-2,
  .col-xs-3,
  .col-xs-4,
  .col-xs-5,
  .col-xs-6,
  .col-xs-7,
  .col-xs-8,
  .col-xs-9,
  .col-xs-10,
  .col-xs-11,
  .col-xs-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xs-11 {
    width: 91.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-xs-10 {
    width: 83.33333333333334%;
  }
  .col-xs-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xs-8 {
    width: 66.66666666666666%;
  }
  .col-xs-7 {
    width: 58.333333333333336%;
  }
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xs-5 {
    width: 41.66666666666667%;
  }
  .col-xs-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
  }
  .col-xs-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 16.666666666666664%;
  }
  .col-xs-1 {
    width: 8.333333333333332%;
  }
}


}
.table>thead>tr>th,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg no-modal-header">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x">×</i>
                </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default no-print pull-right" style="margin-right:15px;" onclick="window.print();">
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> <?= lang('print'); ?></button>
      <?php if ($logo) {
                    ?>
      <div class="text-cente no-print" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
        <img src="<?= base_url() . 'assets/uploads/logos/' . $biller->logo; ?>" alt="<?= $biller->company && $biller->company != '-' ? $biller->company : $biller->name; ?>">
      </div>
      <?php
                } ?>
        <div class="well well-sm no-print">
          <div class="row bold">
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <p class="bold">
                <?= lang('date'); ?>:
                  <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->date); ?><br>
                    <?= lang('ref'); ?>:
                      <?= $inv->reference_no; ?><br>
                        <?php if (!empty($inv->return_sale_ref)) {
                                    echo lang('return_ref') . ': ' . $inv->return_sale_ref;
                                    if ($inv->return_id) {
                                        echo ' <a data-target="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal" href="' . admin_url('sales/modal_view/' . $inv->return_id) . '"><i class="fa fa-external-link no-print"></i></a><br>';
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<br>';
                                    }
                                } ?>
                        <?= lang('sale_status'); ?>:
                          <?= lang($inv->sale_status); ?><br>
                            <?= lang('payment_status'); ?>:
                              <?= lang($inv->payment_status); ?><br>
                                <?= $inv->payment_method ? lang('payment_method') . ': ' . lang($inv->payment_method) : ''; ?>
                                  <?php
                                if ($inv->payment_method == 'cod' || $inv->payment_method == 'bank' && $inv->attachment) {
                                    ?>
                                    <a href="<?= admin_url('welcome/download/' . $inv->attachment) ?>" title="<?= lang('attachment') ?>" class="tip">
                                      <i class="fa fa-chain"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                      <?php if ($inv->payment_status != 'paid' && $inv->due_date) {
                                    echo '<br>' . lang('due_date') . ': ' . $this->sma->hrsd($inv->due_date);
                                } ?>
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">

          <?php if ($Settings->invoice_view == 1) {
                        ?>
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <h1>
              <?= lang('tax_invoice'); ?>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <?php
                    } ?>


        </div>
        <?php
                $col = $Settings->indian_gst ? 5 : 4;
                if ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0) {
                    $col++;
                }
                if ($Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                    $col++;
                }
                if ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0 && $Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                    $tcol = $col - 2;
                } elseif ($Settings->product_discount && $inv->product_discount != 0) {
                    $tcol = $col - 1;
                } elseif ($Settings->tax1 && $inv->product_tax > 0) {
                    $tcol = $col - 1;
                } else {
                    $tcol = $col;
                }
    
    
                ?>

          <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
            <?php if ($Settings->invoice_view == 1) {
                        ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
              <h1>
                <?= lang('tax_invoice'); ?>
              </h1>
            </div>
            <?php
                    } ?>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-2" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                    <?php echo $this->lang->line('to'); ?>:

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-10 pull-left" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                    <strong>
                                    <p>
                                        <small><?= $customer->company && $customer->company != '-' ? $customer->company : $customer->name; ?></small>
                                    </p>
                                    <?= $customer->company && $customer->company != '-' ? '' : 'Attn: ' . $customer->name ?>
                                </strong></p>
                    </strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-right: 0px;">
                    <small>
                                    <?php if ($customer->vat_no != '-' && $customer->vat_no != '') {
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('vat_no') . ': ' . $customer->vat_no;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->gst_no != '-' && $customer->gst_no != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('gst_no') . ': ' . $customer->gst_no;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf1 != '-' && $customer->cf1 != '') {
    
                                        echo lang('ccf1') . ': ' . $customer->cf1;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf2 != '-' && $customer->cf2 != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf2') . ': ' . $customer->cf2;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf3 != '-' && $customer->cf3 != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf3') . ': ' . $customer->cf3;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf4 != '-' && $customer->cf4 != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf4') . ': ' . $customer->cf4;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf5 != '-' && $customer->cf5 != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf5') . ': ' . $customer->cf5;
                                    }
                                    if ($customer->cf6 != '-' && $customer->cf6 != '') {
    
                                        echo '<br>' . lang('ccf6') . ': ' . $customer->cf6;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <?php
                        echo '<small>' . $customer->address . '<div>' . $customer->city . ' ' . $customer->postal_code . ' ' . $customer->state . '</div><div>' . $customer->country . '</div>';
    
                        ?>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                <small><?php echo lang('tel') . ': ' . $customer->phone . '<div>' . lang('email') . ': ' . $customer->email . "</div>";
                            ?></small>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped print-table order-table" style="page-break-inside:auto">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2"><small>SALES&nbsp;PERSON</small></th>
                  <th colspan="2"><small>REFERENCE&nbsp;NO</small></th>
                  <th colspan="2"><small>INVOICE&nbsp;DATE</small></th>
                  <th colspan="2"><small>PAID&nbsp;BY</small></th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><small><?= $created_by->first_name ?></small></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><small><?= $inv->reference_no ?></small></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><small><?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->date) ?></small></td>
                  <td colspan="2"><small><?= $payments[0]->paid_by ?></small></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><small>NO</small></th>
                  <th><small>DESCRIPTION</small></th>
                  <th><small>QTY</small></th>
                  <th><small>UNIT</small></th>
                  <th><small>SUB&nbsp;TOTAL</small></th>
                  <th><small>%</small></th>
                  <th class="text-right"><small>TOTAL</small></th>
                </tr>
                <?php $r = 1;
    
                        if ($rows) {
                            foreach ($rows as $row):
    
                                ?>
                <tr class="str" style="<?php if ($r == 9) {
                                    echo 'page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto;';
                                } ?>">
                  <td class="std"><small><?= $r ?></small></td>
                  <td class="std"><small><?= $row->product_name ?></small></td>
                  <td class="std"><small><?= $this->sma->formatQuantity($row->unit_quantity) ?></small>
                  </td>
                  <td class="std">
                    <small><?= number_format((float)$row->unit_price + $row->item_discount, 2, '.', '') ?></small>
                  </td>
                  <td class="std">
                    <small><?= number_format((float)($row->unit_price) * ($row->unit_quantity), 2, '.', '') ?></small>
                  </td>
                  <td class="std">
                    <small><?= number_format((float)$row->item_discount, 2, '.', '') ?></small></td>
                  <td class="text-right"><small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal) ?></small>
                  </td>

                </tr>


                <?php
                                $r++;
    
    
                            endforeach;
                        }
                        if ($return_rows) {
                            echo '<tr class="warning"><td colspan="100%" class="no-border"><strong>' . lang('returned_items') . '</strong></td></tr>';
                            foreach ($return_rows as $row):
                                ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td><small><?= $r ?></small></td>
                    <td><small><?= $row->product_name ?></small></td>
                    <td><small><?= $this->sma->formatQuantity($row->unit_quantity) ?></small></td>
                    <td>
                      <small><?= number_format((float)$row->unit_price + $row->item_discount, 2, '.', '') ?></small>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <small><?= number_format((float)($row->unit_price) * ($row->unit_quantity), 2, '.', '') ?></small>
                    </td>
                    <td><small><?= number_format((float)$row->item_discount, 2, '.', '') ?></small></td>
                    <td class="text-right"><small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($row->subtotal) ?></small>
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                  <?php
                                $r++;
                            endforeach;
                        }
                        ?>

              </tbody>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class=""><small style="float: right;"><?= lang('total'); ?></small></th>
                  <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                    <small "><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? (($inv->total + $inv->product_tax) + ($return_sale->total + $return_sale->product_tax)) : ($inv->total + $inv->product_tax)); ?></small>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        if ($inv->order_tax != 0) {
                            echo '<tr><th colspan="6><small>' . lang('tax') . '</th><th class="text-right"colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->order_tax + $return_sale->order_tax) : $inv->order_tax) . '</small></th>
                </tr>'; } if ($inv->order_discount != 0) { echo '
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('order_discount') . '</small></th>
                  <th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->order_discount + $return_sale->order_discount) : $inv->order_discount) . '</small></th>
                </tr>'; } if ($inv->shipping != 0) { echo '
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('shipping') . '</th><th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($inv->shipping) . '</small></th>
                </tr>'; } if ($return_sale) { if ($return_sale->surcharge != 0) { echo '
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small>' . lang('return_surcharge') . '</small></th>
                  <th class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale->surcharge) . '</small></th>
                </tr>'; } } if ($Settings->indian_gst) { if ($inv->cgst > 0) { $cgst = $return_sale ? $inv->cgst + $return_sale->cgst : $inv->cgst; echo '
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('cgst') . '</small></td>
                  <td class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($cgst) : $cgst) . '</small></td>
                </tr>'; } if ($inv->sgst > 0) { $sgst = $return_sale ? $inv->sgst + $return_sale->sgst : $inv->sgst; echo '
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('sgst') . '</small></td>
                  <td class="text-right" colspan="2"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($sgst) : $sgst) . '</small></td>
                </tr>'; } if ($inv->igst > 0) { $igst = $return_sale ? $inv->igst + $return_sale->igst : $inv->igst; echo '
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6"><small>' . lang('igst') . '</small></td>
                  <td class="text-right" colspan="6"><small>' . ($Settings->format_gst ? $this->sma->formatMoney($igst) : $igst) . '</small></td>
                </tr>'; } } if ($pos_settings->rounding || $inv->rounding != 0) { ?>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small><?= lang('rounding'); ?></small></th>
                  <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                    <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($inv->rounding); ?></small></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="6" class=""><small style="float: right;"><?= lang('grand_total'); ?></small></th>
                  <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                    <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? (($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding) + $return_sale->grand_total) : ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)); ?></small>
                  </th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                        } else {
                            ?>
                  <tr>
                    <th colspan="6" class="text-right"><small style="float: right;"><?= lang('grand_total'); ?></small></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                      <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->grand_total + $return_sale->grand_total) : $inv->grand_total); ?></small>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                        }
                        if ($inv->paid < ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)) {
                            ?>
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="6" class=""><small style="float: right;"><?= lang('paid_amount'); ?></small></th>
                      <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                        <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney($return_sale ? ($inv->paid + $return_sale->paid) : $inv->paid); ?></small>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th colspan="6" class=""><small style="float: right;">Due Amount</small></th>
                      <th colspan="2" class="text-right">
                        <small><?= $this->sma->formatMoney(($return_sale ? (($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding) + $return_sale->grand_total) : ($inv->grand_total + $inv->rounding)) - ($return_sale ? ($inv->paid + $return_sale->paid) : $inv->paid)); ?></small>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        } ?>
                      <td colspan='8'>
                        <strong><small>Please Note : Any deposit balances are due prior to the above Confirmed
                                    Product Delivery Date</small></strong>
                        <br>
                        <small>All goods remain the property of Arcadia Traders untill paid in full.</small>
                        <br>
                        <small>- Please use invoice number as reference for all payments.</small>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
              </tfoot>

            </table>
          </div>

          <?= $Settings->invoice_view > 0 ? $this->gst->summary($rows, $return_rows, ($return_sale ? $inv->product_tax + $return_sale->product_tax : $inv->product_tax)) : ''; ?>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                <?php
                        if ($inv->note || $inv->note != '') {
                            ?>
                  <div class="well well-sm">
                    <p class="bold">
                      <?= lang('note'); ?>:</p>
                    <div>
                      <?= $this->sma->decode_html($inv->note); ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                        }
                        if ($inv->staff_note || $inv->staff_note != '') {
                            ?>
                    <div class="well well-sm staff_note">
                      <p class="bold">
                        <?= lang('staff_note'); ?>:</p>
                      <div>
                        <?= $this->sma->decode_html($inv->staff_note); ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                        } ?>
              </div>

              <?php if ($customer->award_points != 0 && $Settings->each_spent > 0) {
                        ?>
              <div class="col-xs-5 pull-left">
                <div class="well well-sm">
                  <?=
                                '<p>' . lang('this_sale') . ': ' . floor(($inv->grand_total / $Settings->each_spent) * $Settings->ca_point)
                                . '<br>' .
                                lang('total') . ' ' . lang('award_points') . ': ' . $customer->award_points . '</p>'; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php
                    } ?>


                <div class="order_barcodes no-print">
                  <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <div style="max-width:200px; padding-top:7px;">
                            <img src="<?= admin_url('misc/barcode/' . $this->sma->base64url_encode($inv->reference_no) . '/code128/74/0/1'); ?>" alt="<?= $inv->reference_no; ?>" class="bcimg">
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                          <div style="max-width:70px">
                            <?= $this->sma->qrcode('link', urlencode(admin_url('sales/view/' . $inv->id)), 2); ?>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

                  <br>


                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right no-print">
                  <div class="well well-sm">
                    <p>
                      <?= lang('created_by'); ?>:
                        <?= $inv->created_by ? $created_by->first_name . ' ' . $created_by->last_name : $customer->name; ?>
                          <br>
                          <?= lang('date'); ?>:
                            <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->date); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php if ($inv->updated_by) {
                                ?>
                    <p>
                      <?= lang('updated_by'); ?>:
                        <?= $updated_by->first_name . ' ' . $updated_by->last_name; ?><br>
                          <?= lang('update_at'); ?>:
                            <?= $this->sma->hrld($inv->updated_at); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php
                            } ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if (!$Supplier || !$Customer) {
                    ?>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is full of irrelevant PHP. Please replace the php with rendered HTML in a [mcve] and add relevant framework files

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But it involves many files for libraries and frontend included so it really is not possible to regenerate the problem here

Answer (score 0):

You are using `colspan="6"`, remove that, hopefully it will solve your issue.

Comment: Using colspan because I want that to span 6 columns

Comment: Its very hard to give you solution, coz of irrelevant PHP, but what I can suggest, first remove `<small>` and and in class `text-right'` use `!important`